# Angular 2 delay rendering of router-outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm developing an Angular 2 app with multiple components that rely on some data that is loaded from the server via the http-service (it's data about the user and his roles).

Most of my route components throw errors within their ngOnInit() methods if this data is not already loaded. The data is loaded and stored within a service that is injected in all components.

Is there a way to delay the rendering of the current route within my root-component until the http call is finished?

Otherwise I would have to implement some kind of check and retry mechanism within the ngOnInit of all the route components, which would be very awkward.

I already tried to hide the router-outlet element until the call finished but this leads to an error saying "Cannot find primary outlet to load xxx"

Comment: The service is the same everwhere? If yes, you could use APP_INITIALIZER to handle this problem

Comment: You can use `Resolve` class and create a `Resolver` as a data provider for your components, it gathers data before your component is initialized.

Answer (score 6):

There is an option to delay of router initial navigation when creating Router module:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    // routes here
], {
    initialNavigation: false // the propery to delay navigation
}),
```

Later the initial navigation can be triggered via Angular Router, like this:

```
this.router.initialNavigation();
```

Comment: The connection page shows before the log shows:

> Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
client.js:67 [HMR] connected

Answer (score 3):

I accomplished this with a CanActivate guard.  The key to making it work is returning an Observable from the canActivate method.  That way, you can delay as long as you need to.

```
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { StateService } from '../../_services/state.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Injectable()
export class LoadingGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private state: StateService) {}

    public canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        if (!this.state.loading$.getValue()) { 
            return Observable.of(true); 
        }

        let subject = new Subject<boolean>();
        let subscription = this.state.loading$.subscribe(value => {
            if (!value) {
                subject.next(true);
                subject.complete();

                subscription.unsubscribe();
            }
        });

        return subject;
    }
}
```

Above, StateService is a service that evaluates the current user and pre-caches some data for the rest of the app.  It has a subject named `loading$` that returns false when loading has completed.

All that's left is to declare the guard in the app module.

```
import { LoadingGuard } from './app/loading-guard/loading-guard';
// other imports omitted

@NgModule({
    // other module properties omitted
    providers: [LoadingGuard]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then declare the guard in your routing.

```
import { LoadingGuard } from './app/loading-guard/loading-guard';
// other imports omitted

export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
    { path: 'app', component: AppComponent, 
      canActivate: [LoadingGuard], 
      children: [
        { path: 'index', component: IndexComponent },
        // child routes omitted
      ] },
    { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'sign-in' }
];
```

For reference, here's the documentation on CanActivate:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html

Comment: had to thumbs down, you used stateSevice with no example or link to such service. your answer is incomplete, and wastes peoples time.

Comment: I was able to track down the code alluding to `$loading` for future users
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/a-guide-to-managing-loading-state-for-angular-app-api-requests-83b7429d0e3a

Comment: I can see how that is confusing.  StateService, in this example, will have to be replaced with your own code.  However you keep track of when your application is finished loading.  Listen for the loading completion.  Then return true from `canActivate()`.